# Terraform for_each argument is unsuitable error

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sns

I'm trying to get my terraform for perform a for_each argument, but getting the below error;

**The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.**

My code looks like;

sns.tf

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "jobs-sns" {
  for_each                          = local.sns-topic
  sqs_success_feedback_sample_rate  = "100"
}
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  sns-topic = [
    "jobs-sns00",
    "jobs-sns01", 
    "jobs-sns02",  
    "jobs-sns03",
    "jobs-sns04"
  ]
```

Almost there with the code, feels like a real simple thing I'm missing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options. The first one is probably the one to make your code work faster. You would only need to do the following:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "jobs-sns" {
  for_each                          = toset(local.sns-topic)
  sqs_success_feedback_sample_rate  = "100"
}
```

Note that the built-in `toset` function is used [1] (set mentioned in the error). Alternatively, you could change your local variable a bit. Instead of this:

```
locals {
  sns-topic = [
    "jobs-sns00",
    "jobs-sns01", 
    "jobs-sns02",  
    "jobs-sns03",
    "jobs-sns04"
  ]
}
```

You would do something like (map mentioned in the error):

```
locals {
  sns-topic = {
    topic0 = "jobs-sns00",
    topic1 = "jobs-sns01", 
    topic2 = "jobs-sns02",  
    topic3 = "jobs-sns03",
    topic4 = "jobs-sns04"
  }
```

This is because the `for_each` meta-argument [1] is working with variables which are key value pairs. The one you have is a list of values. Make sure to understand how `for_each` works before using it.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the for_each in the sns.tf to;

> for_each      = toset( ["jobs-sns00", "jobs-sns01",
> "jobs-sns03", "jobs-sns04"] )

Worked ok and picked up the correct values

Comment: Isn't that the same as my answer?